# I know it's a scam, but what is it?

Tags: scams, cryptocurrency

From time to time I receive a message on Twitter like the following:

> tavis
> Login URL...eth0033.c o m
> login name...Adam1986
> password...1986Adam
> assets≈41BTC
> Help me transfer 0.7btc to your brother

You don't have to tell me it's a scam. Of course it is.

But what is it? Is it an advance fee scam? Are they trying to gain access to any wallet I may use to connect? Money laundering? Or is it something else?

Comment: Looks like they're asking you to log in from your IP to move stolen crypto. This way, if someone traces the transfer they'll come to you.

Comment: @littleadv Nah, I've poked around at a few of these (I got the same format). It's a bare-bones fake site; broken links and non-functional sections everywhere. Their goal will be to convince you that they're rich, and rope you into a "manage my money for me" scam, where they send you fake money and you turn it into un-refundable giftcards you send back to them.